# Stopping drawing mode as soon as releasing a shape on the map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/0w3en65n/). How I can force the Google Map to quit the drawing mode when the drawing of first object is done?

As you can see in the demo the drawing mode stay on by each of selected type until user clicks on "Stop Drawing" control but I need to update this to auto detected format.

Here is the code I have:

```
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var drawingStyle = {
        strokeWeight: 0,
        fillOpacity: 0.45,
        editable: true,
        draggable: true
    };
    var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({

        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: [
            google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
            google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
            google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE]
        },
        rectangleOptions: drawingStyle,
        polygonOptions: drawingStyle,
        circleOptions: drawingStyle
    });
    drawingManager.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation states that these events exist on the DrawingManager:

- circlecomplete    | Circle    | This event is fired when the user has finished drawing a circle.
- markercomplete    | Marker    | This event is fired when the user has finished drawing a marker.
- overlaycomplete   | OverlayCompleteEvent | This event is fired when the user has finished drawing an overlay of any type.
- polygoncomplete   | Polygon   | This event is fired when the user has finished drawing a polygon.
- polylinecomplete  | Polyline  | This event is fired when the user has finished drawing a polyline.
- rectanglecomplete | Rectangle | This event is fired when the user has finished drawing a rectangle.

If you want to do something when they occur, add a listener for them:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager,'overlaycomplete',function() {
    drawingManager.setOptions({drawingMode: null, drawingControl: false});
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzv3xfmb/)

code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
    center: {
      lat: 45,
      lng: -85
    },
    zoom: 5
  });

  var drawingStyle = {
    strokeWeight: 0,
    fillOpacity: 0.45,
    editable: true,
    draggable: true
  };
  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({

    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
      ]
    },
    rectangleOptions: drawingStyle,
    polygonOptions: drawingStyle,
    circleOptions: drawingStyle
  });
  drawingManager.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function() {
    drawingManager.setOptions({
      drawingMode: null,
      drawingControl: false
    });
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,drawing"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="margin: 0.6em;"></div>
```