# Not Able to Stop/End Drawing Mode Automatically After One Draw On Map Using Custom Button

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using following code and [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/j5qvLdsx/) to add a Rectangle drawing to the Map using a custom button (Not Google Maps Built In Drawing Toolbar) which is adding the shape but is not stopping/ending the drawing mode **Automatically** after finishing the draw.

I tried adding

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map.drawingManager, "overlaycomplete", function(event){                   
    map.drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
});
```

but still not stopping the drawing mode

```
<button onclick="drawRec();">Draw Rectangle</button>

var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager();
function drawRec() {
    drawingManager.setOptions({
        drawingMode : google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE,
        drawingControl : false,
        drawingControlOptions : {
            position : google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes : [ google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE ]
        },
        rectangleOptions : {
            strokeColor : '#6c6c6c',
            strokeWeight : 3.5,
            fillColor : '#926239',
            fillOpacity : 0.6,
            editable: true,
          draggable: true
        }   
});
drawingManager.setMap(map);

}
google.maps.event.addListener(map.drawingManager, "overlaycomplete", function(event){                   
    map.drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
});  
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue on Stopping Drawing Mode As Soon As Releasing A Shape On The Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27578366/issue-on-stopping-drawing-mode-as-soon-as-releasing-a-shape-on-the-map)

Comment: Hi Again, but as you can see on the Post I was not using any Custom Button for drawing and it was using built in toolbar

Comment: well dont' you think `Using Custom Button` is enough to explain this :-) also I mentioned in the post `(Not Google Maps Built In Drawing Toolbar )` so I am not sure how to explain this more

Comment: Currently I have to click on `Stop Drawing` button to stop another drawing but how can I do this stopping exactly after finishing drawing without explicitly clicking on that button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

duplicate of question: [Issue on Stopping Drawing Mode As Soon As Releasing A Shape On The Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27578366/issue-on-stopping-drawing-mode-as-soon-as-releasing-a-shape-on-the-map), you just need to check and see if the rectangle already exists before starting a new one:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(overlay) {
  // keep reference to the overlay
  rectangle = overlay;
  drawingManager.setOptions({
    drawingMode: null,
    drawingControl: false
  });
});
```

Then in `drawRec`, check to see if it already exists or not, and if it does either remove it from the map or prevent the code from drawing another one.

```
function drawRec() {
  //Setting options for the Drawing Tool. In our case, enabling Polygon shape.
  if (!!rectangle && !!rectangle.overlay && !!rectangle.overlay.setMap) {
    rectangle.overlay.setMap(null);
  }
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/j5qvLdsx/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var rectangle;
var map;
var drawingManager;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 44.5452,
      lng: -78.5389
    },
    zoom: 9
  });
  drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager();
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(overlay) {
    rectangle = overlay;
    drawingManager.setOptions({
      drawingMode: null,
      drawingControl: false
    });
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);


function drawRec() {
  //Setting options for the Drawing Tool. In our case, enabling Polygon shape.
  if (!!rectangle && !!rectangle.overlay && !!rectangle.overlay.setMap) {
    rectangle.overlay.setMap(null);
  }
  drawingManager.setOptions({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE,
    drawingControl: false,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE]
    },
    rectangleOptions: {
      strokeColor: '#6c6c6c',
      strokeWeight: 3.5,
      fillColor: '#926239',
      fillOpacity: 0.6,
      editable: true,
      draggable: true
    }

  });
  drawingManager.setMap(map);

}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="drawRec();">Draw Rectangle</button>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
```